# Setting chai config globally (once for all tests)

Tags: node.js, typescript, chai

Almost all my test files contains multiple configs for `chai`, for example:

```
import chai from 'chai';
import chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised';
...
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
chai.config.includeStack = true;
const expect = chai.expect;
```

Is there any way or pattern to do this only once for all of my tests? (especially the `config` part)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

Create a file called 'chai-local.js'. In that file, do all the things you're doing in your example, but export the final chai.

`export default chai;`

When you need chai, instead of importing from it's source, import from `chai-local.js`. You'll have all of your configuration and extensions every time.

`import chai from 'chai-local.js'`;